# Unable to turn off hardware airplane mode

Tags: airplane-mode

Whenever my laptop goes to sleep mode, or I leave it unattended for sometime the hardware airplane mode gets turned on by itself! and toggling the hardware button does not work. I have tried:

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

it shows

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

followed by:

```
sudo rfkill unblock
```

also,

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

Nothing seems to work! I have to restart my computer EVERYTIME! Would be glad if someone can please help me out!
P.s. I have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: Check for either a 1) find the hard switch on your computer to disable wifi, or 2) find/use the function key which does the same thing.

Comment: Umm I have tried the function key (f12) which also has the airplane mode toggle.. I am not sure if there is supposed to be any other sort of hardware switch for it?

Comment: Some laptops have a hard switch located along the left/right/front edge that disables wifi. It's easy to bump sometimes, and not even know it.

Comment: I dont have any such button it seems :(

Comment: When you tried the function key, did you use just the F12 key, or did you have to use FN+F12?

Comment: normal f12 that has the airplone mode drawn on it. It usually works for other scenarios, just this particular one doesnt work